# Combine Cocos2D (CCAnimation) animation with CocosBuilder (CCBAnimation Manager)?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocosbuilder

I'm integrating CocosBuilder 2.1 into an existing Cocos2D-iphone 2.0 game and having some trouble with animations. There are multiple characters in the game that have both repeating sprite-based animations and movement animations, the latter being dynamically based on changing starting and ending positions.

This was easy in pure Cocos2D. I could just write something like:

```
action = [CCSpawn actions: 
             [CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithDuration:1.0f animation:flippingAnimation restoreOriginalFrame:YES] times:x], 
             flippingAction, nil];
```

However, CocosBuilder uses the CCBANimationManager, which appears to run on an entirely different system. More like:

```
CCBAnimation Manager *animationManager = self.userObject;
[animationManager runAnimationsForSequenceNamed:@"Flipping"]
```

I can design the sprite animations in CocosBuilder, but I think my movement animations will have to stay in Cocos2D code. Is there any way to run the two types of animation simultaneously on the same CCSprite?

Thanks for your help.